# Alphabetical order from VBA Filesystem object

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

I have had this script running on a computer for seven years:

```
 Set F = fs.GetFolder(parentfolder)
 For Each subfolder In F.Subfolders
etc....
```

It has always returned the subfolders in alphabetical order. Running the script on my computer still returns the folders in alphabetical order. But running it on the computer in question returns the folders in some "semi-alphabetical" order, some folders are moved up in the list and others down.

Does anyone have an explanation for why this happened suddenly, and maybe a simple solution? It would be great if I could avoid creating an array and appling the sort function.

best regards
Olle

Comment: The `For Each` does not guarantee ordering. You need to come up with a solution to order the items. There are some solutions around to sort an array.

Comment: It seems a bit peculiar to me that "For Each" sometimes does things in order and other times not. Something must have affected the way it operates, since it has been working flawlessly for 7 years until now.

Comment: It's not random, since it "works" consistently on one computer but not another, but it may be dependent on something *outside of VBA*, such as an OS default which has somehow changed.